# making a sentence recursive in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, recursion

I have a table:

```
id owner   ex_id
1  jack    -
2  joe     -
3  charlie 1
4  bill    3
5  helen   2
6  jack    5
7  anna    4
8  Kurt    7
```

It is possible to have in a select sentence (not a program, just sql) something like "get all the ex_id´s from id 7":

```
id 7: anna, bill, charlie, jack
```

(7 point to 4, 4 point to 3, 3 point to 1, 1 dont have property so it ends)

TIA

Comment: No. MaySQL has no feature for this. However, this question has been asked quite some times before. Maybe you can search those answers for advice on how to work around this.

Comment: MySQL is not advanced enough to have recursive queries, you will need to do that in a program (or a stored procedure)

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql recursive self join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457572/mysql-recursive-self-join)

Comment: B.t.w. I've heard 'query' and 'statement', and 'command', but never 'sentence' in this context.

Comment: Is not the same question:
"Can I find out all the distinct values contained under 'X' using a single self join?"
Im not asking to use a self join, Im talking about any way to accomplish the task and in their quest, a concat ws & group can solve the case. Im afraid Is not my case

Comment: You can't do it with MySQL's `select` capabilities, but for a less elegant solution than Oracle's `CONNECT BY` OR `WITH RECURSIVE` in Postgres, you might want to read Erick Ringot's comment on the [MySQL Select doc page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) regarding recursion, as he does seem to present a stored procedure approach, which you might or might not find any more desirable than just doing it in your application layer, the latter would be my advice if MySQL is a fixed element of your decision. There are reasons stored procs aren't terribly fashionable.

Comment: Thanks, Barry Johnson. You put some lights on my research. Dont know if I will use it, but is a way to solve my problem. Helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to perform such a hierarchical query using pure SQL in MySQL, sorry to say.

Oracle can do it.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm But that's not what you asked.

Comment: Pretty much every other DBMS can do this nowadays, not only Oracle. Even SQLite can do it now.